# keydown doesn't work in threejs canvas, OrbitControls on

Tags: javascript, forms, three.js

I am working on a threejs demo, it has couple of objects within. What I want is a `form` element at the position atop the canvas, where a user can input a text.

---

**Background**

I am creating a form dynamically, using the below function, which seem to work perfectly fine.

```
function createInput() {
    var form = document.createElement( 'form' );
    form.className = 'form-inline';
    form.style.zIndex = 100;
    form.style.position = 'absolute';
    form.style.top = '0px';
    form.style.left = '0px';
    var div = document.createElement( 'div' );
    div.className = 'form-group';
    form.appendChild( div );
    var input = document.createElement( 'input' );
    input.id = "newId";
    input.type = 'email';
    input.className = 'form-control form-control-sm';
    input.placeholder = 'Email..'
    input.name = 'email';
    var button = document.createElement( 'button' );
    button.id = "submitLabel";
    button.type = 'button';
    button.className = 'btn btn-primary btn-sm';
    button.innerHTML = "Put";
    var trashButton = document.createElement( 'button' );
    trashButton.id = "trashLabel";
    trashButton.type = 'button';
    trashButton.className = 'btn btn-danger btn-sm';
    trashButton.innerHTML = "Del";
    div.appendChild( input );
    form.appendChild( button );
    form.appendChild( trashButton );
}
```

**Note that** I am using `OrbitControls` in my canvas. 
Below is the structure of my html. It has two sections - one of search panel which is completely separate and another is `canvas` element which is being loaded through `iframe` element.

[image]

My orbit controls are instantiated as `controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, container );` where the container referred to as `renderer.domElement` - i.e, `canvas` element.

---

**Issue**

Unfortunately, the key inputs don't work in the `input` of the form. The element , i.e., `input` and `button` is focussed on clicking but `input` doesn't register any key stroke.

When I checking in the list of Event Listeners, keydown is attached to the window.

[image]
[image]

When I remove this particular `keydown` event in the console debugger, the form starts to work and nothing breaks, as below.

[image]

---

**Done till now**

I have gone through most of the SO posts on this, as well as this issue which was managed here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4327
However, either I am missing something, or there is a real issue here. I believe I can remove the default `keydown` event which is being attached to the `window`, but I don't think this is more of a workaround.

If anyone would be kind to shed some light on this, it will be real helpful. Let me know if you need anything else from the code.

Comment: Are you using r.101? That has a [bug](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/15693) in OrbitControls. Try the dev branch version.

Comment: Perfect! It works :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try setting OrbitControls.enableKeys = false?

If that allows your events to propagate.. perhaps you can do a onblur / onfocus on your input and toggle OrbitControls.enableKeys.

Comment: Ya, it seems to work but then it's flaky, I will do the blur/ foc on input and see whether that takes me places. Thanks.

Comment: One ques: Do you think it's more of a workaround? I meant: through https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4327 that's what they were trying to rectify, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah it sounds like a workaround for a known issue. But... i can also understand the design constraints that led to it being implemented like that in OrbitControls.

I usually think of OrbitControls.. and indeed anything that isn't in the core three.js library, as a starting point for building a version tailored to your needs. 

Making it listen globally for keys prevents a couple stumbling blocks for people just using the default orbitcontrols to get something going, and it's also kept simple enough to take apart and modify.

Comment: For instance, in the context of VR.. having a dom element steal the key focus while you are wearing a headset would be painful since you cant see the dom elements in VR.

Comment: https://join.slack.com/t/threejs/shared_invite/enQtMzYxMzczODM2OTgxLWE5OTU4OTYxZTZlODk1ZGNjODIyMDZlODM4ZmUyMzNiOWIxMmFjNTYwOTc4MjU0ZmNiODk5MzZiMGJhMTkzZWI If you want to chat about it or general three.js help.

Comment: Lovely! Btw blur and focus work well. I am accepting this as the answer. And probably it will be better to customise `OrbitControls` for my needs.